# Automatically sync two audio recordings in python

Tags: python, audio

I would like to use my video camera to record high quality video and unfortunately subpar audio from the camera's internal microphone, while simultaneously record the audio onto a separate device with a better quality microphone.

Then afterwards automatically sync up the external audio so that it matches the video.

This seems to me to be similar to the problem of bpm detection, but simpler, in that you do not need to find loops of similarity but basically just overlay the audio channels and see where they match the best. Or detect a certain "sync sound" event.

I prefer programming in python and any pointers to some python code that either does this or could serve as a starting point is greatly appreciated.

Update: I have found this [python application](https://github.com/antonxy/audiosync) with [matching Android clapboard](https://github.com/antonxy/audiosync_androidapp) that could do the trick. It seems to work by syncing to a special sound recorded both in the video file and in the external audio file.

Update II: And here is [another one](https://github.com/allisonnicoledeal/VideoSync) in python, that is meant to be used to sync up Yotube videos recorded at the same concert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have now tested [Allison Deal's Video sync](https://github.com/allisonnicoledeal/VideoSync) (also linked under "Update II" in the question) and it seems to do the job.

In the root of its git directory there is a file called "alignment_by_row_channels.py". If you comment in the test code at the end of that file, it can take two mp4 videos and print the time offset between the audio in the two videos.

I tested it with a Canon HF200 video camera and an LG G2 android phone, with talk and finger snaps and very low volume on the video camera. I then manually analyzed the sound tracks with audacity.

The alignment_by_row_channels.py script indicated an offset between the two track of 15.1893 seconds. My manual analysis by looking at waveforms gave 15.181 seconds (audacity does not output less than millisecond resolution, at least not by default).

The difference is only 8.3 milliseconds or thereabouts which seems to indicate that "alignment_by_row_channels.py" does the job.

(Beware that the git repo is hefty, probably due to deleted big objects)

Comment: Python 3 / ffmpeg version can be found at [calib_video_opencv](https://github.com/Algomorph/calib_video_opencv) in sync/offset.py. Note that it already accounts for the 8.3 millisecond (or thereabouts) offset, which is critical for 60 fps video. I haven't found the cause for the offset but empirically confirmed it for the original. With some tweaking and simplifications, you can use the sync_video.py script directly without needing OpenCV (get rid of ```find_calibration_conversion_range``` and ```calib.data``` imports, replace calls with ```find_offset_range```, don't flip, set -te=0, etc.)

Comment: Correction to the above comment: there is nothing wrong with the original code. The offset is appears to be a direct consequence of the difference in delays between the video and the audio in each video file. For my case, I manually measured it to be ~9 ms. I have altered my code to accept that as an argument, so, for utmost precision on high-fps video, you still need to measure those delays manually (conventional wisdom recommends clapping during capture to do so).

Comment: I tried to use this today and I can't seem to find the convert_to_webm library. Do you still have access to it?

Comment: I have made my own repo based on her stuff, but changed a bit,  and I tested it two weeks ago and it seemed to work, although I tested it on two identical files. Still that should run through all code https://github.com/jeorgen/align-videos-by-sound

Comment: Maybe you asked Greg I just realised, but your comment turned up in my mailbox :)

Answer (score 1):

Used this document and it worked for me:

http://www.dsg-bielefeld.de/dsg_wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/video_syncing_fun.pdf

```
praat_command = '{} {} {} {}'.format(
    praat, praat_script, sound, sound_studio)
sound_offset_time = check_output(
    praat_command, shell=True).decode("utf-16")
```

Praat script:

```
form Cross Correlate two Sounds
    sentence input_sound_1
    sentence input_sound_2
    real start_time 0
    real end_time 30
endform

Open long sound file... 'input_sound_1$'
Extract part: 0, 30, "no"
Extract one channel... 1
sound1 = selected("Sound")
Open long sound file... 'input_sound_2$'
Extract part: 0, 30, "no"
Extract one channel... 1
sound2 = selected("Sound")

select sound1
plus sound2
Cross-correlate: "peak 0.99", "zero"
offset = Get time of maximum: 0,0, "Sinc70"

writeInfoLine: 'offset'
```

Answer (score 1):

Having found no tool to sync the start of video/audio recordings,
but finding more such questions,
I decided to make a tool myself: syncstart.
It is now on [github](https://github.com/rpuntaie/syncstart) and [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/syncstart/).

Comment: This was really useful, thanks!  I wanted to use it from a command line, so I had to comment out the lines that depended on python-tk, but then it worked like a charm!