# How to sync two audio files in python?

Tags: python-3.x, audio

I have two short 2-3 minute .wav files that were recorded within 1 minute of eachother. They could be anywhere from 0-60 seconds off. I'd like to sync them together. There is a sync tone that is played, and present in both audio files. There is very little audio in them besides the loud sync tone, it is very obvious when viewed in audacity.

I've tried every solution listed here [Automatically sync two audio recordings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394937/automatically-sync-two-audio-recordings-in-python)
and none of them work. They all share the same problem, when they get to this method:

```
def find_freq_pairs(freqs_dict_orig, freqs_dict_sample):
    time_pairs = []
    for key in freqs_dict_sample.keys():  # iterate through freqs in sample
        if freqs_dict_orig.has_key(key):  # if same sample occurs in base
            for i in range(len(freqs_dict_sample[key])):  # determine time offset
                for j in range(len(freqs_dict_orig[key])):
                    time_pairs.append((freqs_dict_sample[key][i], freqs_dict_orig[key][j]))

    return time_pairs
```

Each time, the inner for loop ends up having to do (500k ^ 2) iterations for each of the 512 keys in the freqs_dict dictionary. This will take many months to run. This is with two 3-4 second audio files. With 1-2 minute audio files, it was (5m+ * 5m+) iterations. I think perhaps the library broke with python3, since everyone on that thread seemed happy with it...

Does anyone know a better way to sync two audio files with python?

Thank you