# Synchronize + merge audio of one video file into another

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, synchronization, fingerprinting

Suppose the following:

- I got two video files with audio
- They are pretty much the same (going by 'images'), but differ in codec, quality, .. and audio.

To have a more specific example, furtermore suppose:

- Video 1 (the 'target') is running @24 FPS in 2160p [HEVC]. The first 25 seconds of audio and video are not "belonging"/unessential to the video depicted.
- Video 2 is running @30 FPS in 720p [X264]. The first 19 seconds of audio and video are not "belonging"/unessential to the video depicted.

I now want to perfectly merge the audio of "Video 2" into the target Video, so that the audio of both videos pretty match (except e.g. language)

My initial thought would be to synchronize both videos by frames using fingerprinting/hashes similar to various repost checker bots.

Is there an easier method, how would I go from there (preferably using ffmpeg)?
Bonus points if the first 25 seconds of the "Video 1" audio are prepended to the "Video 2" audio while the first 19 seconds are omitted.

Comment: Does a basic command suffice? `ffmpeg -ss 25 -i input1 -ss 19 -i input2 -filter_complex amix -c:v copy output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan Sorry for the late response. This is a start - thank you. As I won't know the values 19 & 25, but have to calculate/determine them - how would I go about there?

Comment: I was assuming you already knew the offset times. You'll need to search of an additional tool or wrapper to provide such functionality. Here's an old, related question: [Automatically sync two audio recordings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25394937/)